# CSS attribute not applied when using css file

Tags: html, css

I have some html like this:

```
<table id="MatrixTable" class="zebra-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: White;">
            <td style="min-width: 31px !important;">
                ...
            </td>
```

As you can see, I set background color to white in the html code.

Next, if I set this in CSS, then it don't work anymore. Strange because when I inspect CSS at runtime (IE F12) I can see that thead / tr has its background-color to white.

```
#MatrixTable thead tr  
{
    background-color: White !important;
}
```

Why is this not working with CSS file? Other things in my css file is properly applied.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your CSS file linked correctly?

Comment: Are there other css files? Can you link to the page where this is occuring?

Comment: make sure u link the css file this way: <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/file.css" />

Comment: Any background color on td/th? What about Firefox/Chrome (`White` vs `white` maybe, I've seen worse than that with old IEs...)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the linked css file is OK because I see the property by inspecting CSS in IE. Furthermore, other CSS properties are applied from the same CSS file. I just have to say that my table is manipulated by jQuery at some time but I cannot figure why 'inlin' css is ok and css-file is not OK.

Comment: white colour is default colour, possible to distinguish it in the web page?

Comment: another thing is the background of TD tags may overlap TR

Comment: sounds like to me you have a css inheritance confliction somewhere, so probs easier if you just show us your css. Perhaps use [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net).

Comment: I use this plugin http://www.mustafaozcan.net/en/page/jQuery-Fixed-Table-Header-Plugin.aspx and when I begin scrolling in my page, header of my table if fixed. If I set CSS background to white in my html code it works (I mean background of header is solid white). If I set this in my css file it doesn't work anymore (I mean background is transparent). Hope it helps.

Comment: may be class="zebra-striped" have conflicting design
And try using firebug in chrome/firefox and make changes in design in runtime , I hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Your given code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/aLQ3R/ You will have to reproduce your bug in JSFiddle otherwise this going to be too localised and unanswerable

Comment: Raheel is right about conflict with "zebra-striped" but I cannot modify this css file.

Answer (score 1):

1. check if your css-file is included properly
2. check if there are other styles overriding your tr style
3. check other (child-) elements (like your `td`) having styles that could nullify this style.
4. correct `White` to `white`
5. check the specificity of your selection rules (inline styles have higher priorities!)

sidenote: avoid `!important` where ever you can, it leads to sloppy style resulting in such problems. It is not meant to be used for these purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS selector instead:

```css
#MatrixTable thead tr td {
    background-color: #FFF !important;
}
```

Comment: but how about the padding between TR & TD?

Comment: what's the difference to`white`? None?

Comment: i don't know. only the asker knows :)

Comment: this will most likely not solve the problem, since it doesn't matter if you write `#fff` or `white`.

Comment: @Christoph similar, i think, but more crossbrowser

Comment: The color-codes are in the standard since css1, they are supported in every browser

Comment: if you are interested: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#color-units. At this point the according RBG-values weren't specified, so the colors could differ in each browser, but in css2.1 they are exactly defined: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#color-units